# How to know if an event was called there for three seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, events, controls

I'm looking for an code example/algorithm to do an action if the user has not entered anything in textbox for a period of 3 seconds.

My scenery: I have a `textbox` that I want submit if the textbox has focus, but the user has not written anything for 3 seconds. is this possible?

Comment: So when the textbox gets focus start counting, and after three seconds intervene by doing some other action? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: @Yuck: ...and don't forget to cancel the other action if the user starts doing something within the three seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` timer. Whenever the text in the textbox changes, (`TextChanged` event) you need to restart the timer to fire in 3 seconds.  If the timer ever fires, this means that 3 seconds have elapsed while the user has not typed anything.

However, be advised that this is very bizarre behavior on behalf of your application, and it is highly unlikely that it will be appreciated by any user out there.

Answer (score 3):

You can have one event in `TextChange` that stores the current time to a variable for any change to the textbox.

Then you can add a `Timer` that fires every second. The timer can check if the textbox has focus, and if it does, if the timestamp in the variable is more than three seconds old (and probably if the textbox is empty or not), and if it is, call your submit method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a ready-made example, but I believe that you could use a `Timer` to accomplish this. Set the timeout to 3000 ms, reset it when the user types into the textbox (use TextChanged or the equivalent event, *not* merely KeyPress which will not fire on right-click menu clipboard pastes and the likes), and in the timer handler, disable the timer (to make sure it doesn't fire repeatedly) and perform whatever logic you like. Also, enable/disable the timer depending on whether the textbox has focus.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example how to hide cursor if user doesn't move the mouse 3 seconds.
You have to do the similar stuff using TextChange event.

```
private DispatcherTimer CursorTimer { get; set; }
private DateTime CursorLastMoveTime { get; set; }

void CursorTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.CursorLastMoveTime);
            if (delta.TotalSeconds > 3)
            {
                CursorTimer.Stop();
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
            }
        }


private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            #region Hide/Show cursor over the main window
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            CursorLastMoveTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (CursorTimer.IsEnabled == false)
                CursorTimer.Start();
            #endregion
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a timer which has an interval of 3000 miliseconds. If the interval is elapsed, an event is triggered and if the user enters text in your textbox, the count is reset.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000;
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);
        textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_GotFocus);
        textBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_LostFocus);
    }

    void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have not entered text in the last 3 seconds!");
    }
}
```

Comment: As others have stated, please be advised that the TextChanged event is a better choice rather than KeyPress as in this example.